# Excel - draw a chart based on a cell containing the string of a range (indirect?)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect, excel-charts

I am trying with Excel formula, to create a chart based on a dynamic string references. To put it short, I have another formula which give me range, like in the cell H7 I have B7:B15, and I want that my chart use something like INDIRECT(H7) as an input.

In the example in the picture, the chart on the right is done by normal way (selecting array manually) and should be identical to what I would obtain.

Excel refuse this and said there is an error, though, interesting fact, the array I am interested in is highlighted.

[image: With INDIRECT]

I have read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183887/using-the-indirect-function-in-a-chart-or-series-formula) that I should use variable, which I did, with the same result:

[image: Name Manager view]
[image: With name manager]

It seems that I have to use some SERIES stuff, but unfortunately, I have german excel, and this SERIES function do not exists in any translation sheet, just SERIESSUM.

To put it short,

1. I have a cell H7 with the string B7:B15 in it
2. I wish to have a chart which references to the content of H7

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: Español SERIES
English SERIES
Nederlands REEKS
Deutsch DATENREIHE
Français SERIE
Italiano SERIE
Português SÉRIE
Svenska SERIE
Dansk SERIE
Norsk SERIE
Suomen kieli SARJA
Russian .SERIES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to this guy [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/can-i-use-an-indirect-type-formula-within-a-chart/25facc4e-9913-4189-8b63-8ac9fc9762bd?db=5) I managed to understand what goes wrong.

When we start with sheet like the upper here:

1. Edit the range cell to be sure that the range refer to the sheet name, for instance H6 shall contain 'Tabelle1'!$A$7:$A$15 and H7 'Tabelle1'!$B$7:$B$15
2. Create a named variable containing an indirect reference to the content of the cell, with ref to sheet name, make the var also linked to the sheet. Ex: var_potato = INDIRECT('Tabelle1'!$H$7) and var_dates = INDIRECT('Tabelle1'!$H$6)
3. create a chart with some dummy curve in it
4. Click on the curve in the chart, in the value field (up) is the serie function (datenreihe in german).
5. Replace the second and third argument of the serie by the variable, referenced with the sheet name =SERIES(Tabelle1!$G$7;Tabelle1!var_dates;Tabelle1!var_potato;2)

This should work.

Pay attention to this 2 rules:

1. Charts cannot have indirect in their formula, that's why we use variables
2. Each cell references as well as variable use have to be done with sheet name, even if it is inside the same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any formula. You need use Table format and Data segmentation:

[image: Example 1]

All you need is select te date range that you need.

[image]

Comment: Hello.Thanks a lot for your help, but this does not answer my question. The thing, I will not use a table, I want to make the chart refering to the input string into a cell at a fixed adress..